# Magento product load - difference between loadByAttribute and load methods

Tags: magento

today I'm fighting with Magento again :) and I found a difference between

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $product_sku);
```

and

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
```

Can anyone exaplain me a difference between these two approaches? I found that when I'm loading a product by sku then when I 'try to re-save it with changed data then I get error exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Varien_Object::save in app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php(153): Varien_Object->__call('save', Array) that's true because once you try to load by sku then another observer sets product's stock item as Varien_Object, that looks like pitfall or I just dont understand it enough, but

I do daily Magento development from its beginnig so I know a lot about system and this is new for me. Thanks in advance, Jaro.

Comment: wow thanks had the same problem, loading it now by sku and after that by id

Comment: Thanks. The first method worked for me and I believe, the second method does not accept variables? it did work when I hard coded a SKU number.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Interesting. While both methods will net you a single product model instance with fully loaded EAV data (provided the third parameter of `loadByAttribute()` is not passed or is `*`), the observers which add stock-related data are different for products vs. product collections, yet both stock information objects are added to the product data key "stock_item". It's debatable, but this feels like a bug. I would think that `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::saveInventoryData()` or `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::_prepareItemForSave()` would handle this.

You could resolve this issue by setting the product stock item fully on your product instance using the `stock_item` object.

Comment: It looks like a kind of bug, one you create a collection you have there products with faked stock information and once you want to change then it fails. It took me 3 days to figure this, because it's happening really deep in core and you don't suspect and expect that. I need to share such information with other save their time and lives :)

Comment: [Become a Magento Contributor](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/MCA-Magento-Contributor-Agreement-230909.pdf) :-)

Comment: it seems that it still happens in 1.8? I faced that problem today.

Answer (score 1):

`loadByAttribute` is a serious misnomer in my opinion because it doesn't actually trigger a `load()`; rather it uses `getResourceCollection()`:

```
public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
{
    $collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
        ->setPage(1,1);
```

Because it doesn't trigger the observer events associated with `load()` it means the resulting product object doesn't include the full set of product data you might want. In my case I needed the "description" attribute and it wasn't included.

There are several ways to resolve this:

- Use a different method to load by SKU:

  ```
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
    $product->load($product->getIdBySku("whatever"));
  ```
- Force the desired attribute data to be included in the default product resource data by visiting `Magento Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Edit attribute > "Used in Product Listing" = "Yes"` and then reindexing. You should then be able to use the attribute data (in the frontend, at least) using `loadByAttribute()`.

See also https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197286/18855