# Magento Get Option Label by Option Code

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to get the **Custom Option Label** based on either the *Option ID* or *Option Code*.  Here's what I have so far:

```
$product_id = $product->getId(); //Get the Product Id
echo '<br /><strong>Product ID:</strong> ' . $product_id;

foreach($product->getCustomOptions() as $o) {
    echo '<br />[Item ID] ' . $o->getItemId() . '<br />[Value ID] ' . $o->getId() . '<br />[Value] ' . $o->getValue() . '<br />[Code] ' . $o->getCode() . '<br />';
}
```

So what I have to work with at this point is:

> Item ID
>
> Value ID
>
> Value
>
> Code

My end goal is to use the option frontend label to see if the label is equal to "Length" as I am trying to use the "Length" value but seeing how custom options all have unique codes, the code is unreliable in terms of fetching just the "length" values for each item in the cart.

How can I use what I have to get the label for the custom options?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try  `getCustomOption($code)`

Comment: @R.S I just did.  I got an error, "Fatal error: Call to undefined function getCustomOptions()".

Comment: What product type are you using simple/config?

Comment: The error is for `getCustomOptions()` not `getCustomOption()` (without 's')

Comment: Also, I am assuming that $code needs to be set to $o->getCode()...

Comment: Ah, I see.  Changing it to getCustomOption() still yields an error... perhaps a model issue?

Comment: Did the code you added to your question work? Also are you trying this on a product list or detail page and is flat catalog enable?

Comment: It's on my cart page.  Yes, the code in my initial question is/was working.

Comment: Can you add the code that load/define `$product`

Comment: Before I get the lecture about editing core files... please be warned that this is just a test on a Magento install on a private server and is a temporary test that will be reverted in the near future.  That being said, the file is app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php and I am in the public function, "getFinalPrice".

Comment: `public function getFinalPrice($qty=null, $product)`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929563/magento-product-load-difference-between-loadbyattribute-and-load-methods .... i'm not sure product instance is loaded .... Try loading the using $productTest = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow these steps:
- create a `test.php` file in your magento root directory and run the codes below.
- it returns an array for each custom option with details.

```
    <?php
        require_once "app/Mage.php";
        Mage::app('default');
        echo "<pre>";

        $productId = 13; // change the product id as your need
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $productOptionCollection = $product->getProductOptionsCollection();
        $customOptions = $productOptionCollection->getData();

        print_r($customOptions);
    ?>
```